# Encrypt iphone executable

Tags: ios, iphone, security, encryption, ipa

I am looking for a way to secure my app resources with Encrypt ( & Decrypt at run time) the app resources (images, db, NSUserDefault values, other files etc).

Is there any easy way to do so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encryption of contents in compiled iOS app ( IPA )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211274/encryption-of-contents-in-compiled-ios-app-ipa)

Comment: @Raptor There are many such ways for encryption. But i want a way where i can decrypt resources which are set in XIB(Button images, image view images etc). Is there any way for this?

Comment: XIB stores layout. Why do you want to encrypt a layout? It will be displayed to users anyway. Also, layout is compiled, only images are not encrypted.

Comment: @Raptor: I do not want to encrypt the XIB file, but my point is if I set an Image to the UIImageview in XIB then where to decrypt the UIImage assigned to that imageview? As we cannot get imagename from UIImage. I hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: You can convert the `UIImage` to `NSData` and encrypt the `NSData` with your favorite encryption algorithm (e.g. DES, RSA, etc)

Comment: @Raptor : How to convert decrypted UIImage to NSData? I am using this but it returns invalid data:
` NSData *dat=UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image);`

Comment: What do you mean by invalid data ?

Comment: As UIImage is encrypted it is not a valid png file so as per apples documentation "UIKIT_EXTERN NSData *UIImagePNGRepresentation(UIImage *image);                               // return image as PNG. May return nil if image has no CGImageRef or invalid bitmap format
"
it returns invalid data.

Comment: Note that if your resources can be decrypted at runtime then a dedicated attacker can extract them in the same way. For the same reason DRM does not work in practice.