# how to erase sensitive information shipped with iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, build

I am a new iOS developer and developing an app with costumed project which has no typical compile options like debug, release, distribute. So I have to config compile options of xcode by myself. That brought some difficulties to me.

Source codes of this project is very sensitive as the app's rival competitor will be interested in the information of source code. To erase information concerned with source code's information, I need help to config compile options of xode. For example, I can find name of functions by profiling this app with intruments and I have no idea how to erase it even after I have set option to turn off "generate debug symbols" of xcode.

How can I erase overall informations concerned with source code? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you are developing in objective-c, you CAN'T get rid of implementation details such as iVar layout & methods. The only thing you can do is obfuscate, which adds problems itself.

Comment: Write it in brainf**k, that'll really screw 'em over!

Comment: Since there are always possibilities to "inspect your code" - the only practical alternative I found is to use a rather complex underlying datastructure that is very hard to figure out - while influencing the logic of the app. Even though it's possible to look at, understanding indices in hashtables with complex structures indexing other tables finally at some stage used to control the code are quite difficult to understand. In most cases the time it takes to understand is more than just recreating it. ps put some strange coercion + self made encryption in there - this will confuse alot...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying [obfuscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) you code. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249148/how-to-encrypt-or-obfuscate-objective-c-code) regarding obfuscating Objective-C code. The problem with obfuscating is that it's possible to reverse it if someone really wants to, so it might be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: thank you all for your answer. My project is written in c/c++. Obfuscation is a great solution as you suggested. But I think completely get rid of debug information may be enough for me. However I don't know to do it with xcode.