# iOS -- Technique for securing SOAP API credentials embedded in binary

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, authentication, https

The answer proposed in [Embed API credentials in iOS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049579/embed-api-credentials-in-ios-code) is not an option for me.

My app communicates with a back-end SOAP API over HTTPS.  My API credentials are sent in every request.

I don't have control over the server implementation, so I'm not able to add an intermediary authentication server and migrate to a token-based implementation.

Because I have to embed my credentials with my app's binary (I understand that this is far from ideal, on principle), **i am looking for best practices to make my credentials *as secure as is possible*.**

From what I've read, I've gathered:

- **Don't** include credentials in an external file (such as a `.plist`)
- **Don't** include credentials as simple `NSString * const` declarations.  (Is using a `char *` safer?)
- **Don't** do something obvious, like put my credentials in an Objective-C singleton called `AuthenticationKeyManager`

I also saw this article: http://applidium.com/en/news/securing_ios_apps_debuggers/
=> *tldr: add release-mode code in the `main.m` to prevent the app from running if a debugger is attached*

Note: I *am* able to implement SSL pinning.

Are there any other measures I can take to safeguard my access credentials?

Answer (score 0):

There is described how create and use encrypted plist: http://aptogo.co.uk/2010/07/protecting-resources/

But aes key from it is stored in `static NSString *sharedKey;`